# Visual studio 2017 - MSBuild command line - "Debug|Win32" is invalid

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line, msbuild

As I Try to compile a c++ solution with MSBuild on the command line

1 - it does not picks the Active configuration per default

2 - as I force it (Debug/Win32), it says it does not exists

3 - same problem if I try different combinations of Release/Win32

```
c:\myproject>"P:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild".exe game2D_sdl.sln /p:useenv=true /m /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug  /p:Platform=Win32
...
     1>c:\myproject\game2D_sdl.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Debug|Win32" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configura
       tion and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration. [Z:\WORK\SD
       L\game2D_sdl\game2D_sdl.sln]
```

[image: Win32 Debug exists !!]

what am I missing ?

regards

Comment: Your screenshot shows project configurations not solution configurations, see the drop downs in the main window toolbar for those

Comment: Can msbuild game2D_sdl.sln /p:useenv=true /m /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Debug  /p:Platform=X86 work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As you use the command to build a .sln(solution) file, please use the
>   solution configuration instead of project configuration.

I create a simple C++ console project. In the ‘CPlusForConfig’ solution I have one project ‘CPlusForConfig’. Take a look at the pic below(My Configuration Manager):
[image]

According to the pic, the solution configuration: Debug/X86 corresponds to project configuration: Debug/win32.

As for your issue, if you want to build the project with project configuration:`Debug/win32`

Use the solution configuration when you build the solution by command like: `msbuild CPlusForConfig.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=X86`

Or use the project configuration when you build the project by command like: `msbuild CPlusForConfig.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=win32`
These two commands both work for you.

In addition: you can open your configuration manager by Right-click solution in Solution explore and choose Configuration manager.
If it is helpful or not, please give me a feedback.